# How to parse HTML with ncbi nih?

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-crawler

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cds_id = "NP_001339842.1" 

fasta_url = ("https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/%s/?report=fasta" %cds_id)
                                
fasta_html = requests.get(fasta_url)
fasta_html.raise_for_status()         

soup = BeautifulSoup(fasta_html.text, "html.parser")
                                
print(soup.select('div > pre > #text'))
```

I hope to parse the sequence data from ncbi but when I search tag`<pre>`, the return is always 'None'. I used 'find' and 'findAll' also, but the result was the same.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you done a "View Source" on that page?  I don't mean the DOM view.  The HTML source, which is what `requests` gets, does not have that code at all.  It's all built dynamically via Javascript.  You would need to use something like Selenium to run the Javascript.  Don't they have an API for you to fetch that?

Answer (score 0):

Just to hint into a direction - extract for example the following parameters and call the api, where the data comes from.

```
...
soup = BeautifulSoup(fasta_html.text, "html.parser")
phid = soup.select_one('[name="ncbi_phid"]').get('content')
id = soup.select_one('[name="ncbi_uidlist"]').get('content')

requests.get(f'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?id={id}&db=protein&report=fasta&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&hide-cdd=on&retmode=html&ncbi_phid={phid}&withmarkup=on&tool=portal&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000').text
```

##### Output

```
>NP_001339842.1 serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2A 56 kDa regulatory subunit gamma isoform isoform g [Homo sapiens]\nMPNKNKKEKESPKAGKSGKSSKEGQDTVESEQISVRKNSLVAVPSTVSAKIKVPVSQPIVKKDKRQNSSR\nFSASNNRELQKLPSLKDVPPADQEKLFIQKLRQCCVLFDFVSDPLSDLKWKEVKRAALSEMVEYITHNRN\nVITEPIYPEVVHMFAVNMFRTLPPSSNPTGAEFDPEEDEPTLEAAWPHLQLVYEFFLRFLESPDFQPNIA\nKKYIDQKFVLQLLELFDSEDPRERDFLKTTLHRIYGKFLGLRAYIRKQINNIFYRFIYETEHHNGIAELL\nEILGSIINGFALPLKEEHKIFLLKVLLPLHKVKSLSVYHPQLAYCVVQFLEKDSTLTEPVVMALLKYWPK\nTHSPKEVMFLNELEEILDVIEPSEFVKIMEPLFRQLAKCVSSPHFQVAERALYYWNNEYIMSLISDNAAK\nILPIMFPSLYRNSKTHWNKTIHGLIYNALKLFMEMNQKLFDDCTQQFKAEKLKEKLKMKEREEAWVKIEN\nLAKANPQYTVYSQASTMSIPVAMETDGPLFEDVQMLRKTVKDEAHQAQKDPKKDRPLARRKSELPQDPHT\nKKALEAHCRADELASQDGR\n\n
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get some meta fields from the page. Then you can get the information you need

```
cds_id = 'NP_001339842.1'
url = f'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/protein/{cds_id}/?report=fasta'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
ncbi_uid = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'ncbi_uidlist'}).get('content')
ncbi_db = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'ncbi_db'}).get('content')
ncbi_phid = soup.find('meta', {'name': 'ncbi_phid'}).get('content')
response = requests.get(f'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sviewer/viewer.fcgi?'
                        f'id={ncbi_uid}&db={ncbi_db}&report=fasta&extrafeat=null&conwithfeat=on&hide-cdd=on&'
                        f'retmode=html&ncbi_phid={ncbi_phid}&withmarkup=on&tool=portal'
                        f'&log$=seqview&maxdownloadsize=1000000')
print(response.text)
```

OUTPUT:

```
>NP_001339842.1 serine/threonine-protein phosphatase 2A 56 kDa regulatory subunit gamma isoform isoform g [Homo sapiens]
MPNKNKKEKESPKAGKSGKSSKEGQDTVESEQISVRKNSLVAVPSTVSAKIKVPVSQPIVKKDKRQNSSR
FSASNNRELQKLPSLKDVPPADQEKLFIQKLRQCCVLFDFVSDPLSDLKWKEVKRAALSEMVEYITHNRN
VITEPIYPEVVHMFAVNMFRTLPPSSNPTGAEFDPEEDEPTLEAAWPHLQLVYEFFLRFLESPDFQPNIA
KKYIDQKFVLQLLELFDSEDPRERDFLKTTLHRIYGKFLGLRAYIRKQINNIFYRFIYETEHHNGIAELL
EILGSIINGFALPLKEEHKIFLLKVLLPLHKVKSLSVYHPQLAYCVVQFLEKDSTLTEPVVMALLKYWPK
THSPKEVMFLNELEEILDVIEPSEFVKIMEPLFRQLAKCVSSPHFQVAERALYYWNNEYIMSLISDNAAK
ILPIMFPSLYRNSKTHWNKTIHGLIYNALKLFMEMNQKLFDDCTQQFKAEKLKEKLKMKEREEAWVKIEN
LAKANPQYTVYSQASTMSIPVAMETDGPLFEDVQMLRKTVKDEAHQAQKDPKKDRPLARRKSELPQDPHT
KKALEAHCRADELASQDGR
```